# Canvas not completely covering webpage in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, canvas, google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension is supposed to cover any webpage completely with a canvas so that the user can, basically, draw on top of it. Right now I am appending the canvas's div to the top of the body. On some sites this doesn't work entirely though. The only reason I can think of is because the body has classes applied to it which could be either providing some DOM content(?) or making it impossible for me to build over content, so then some DOM content still gets placed before my div.

```
canvasDiv = document.createElement("div");
canvasDiv.innerHTML = "<div><canvas id='myuniquecanvas'></canvas></div>";
document.body.insertBefore(canvasDiv, document.body.firstChild);
canvas = document.getElementById("myuniquecanvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.style.position = "absolute";
canvas.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
canvas.style.zIndex = 200;

ctx.canvas.width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
ctx.canvas.height = (window.innerHeight > 0) ? window.innerHeight : screen.height;
ctx.canvas.height += document.body.scrollTop;

//height & width are also changed dynamically via scroll & resize listeners
```

One site I'm having a problem with is Youtube. Below, the black is my canvas, and you can see that my canvas won't cover the bars on the top and side of the page.

[image]

This is what Youtube looks like in the console with my canvas:

[image]

The only thing on top of the div is that long body class, so is one of those classes creating the side bar and top bar? If it is, how do I work around that?

I have no idea how to go about getting my canvas over those items on Youtube's main page, let alone find a solution that will work across the majority of websites. Is my approach here for appending to the top of the body flawed? It clearly allows room for error. Is there a better way to get a canvas/any element on top of an entire webpage?

For example, assuming that the body's classes have something to do with the issue, could I append my own class to the body which would allow me to append something to its top somehow? I'm sort of reaching here because I'm not sure what the issue is.

EDIT:

I set the z-index to 9999999999 and now it's covering the whole area. Not sure what it is about that exact number but it seems to be working.

Comment: Is `<canvas>` within an `<iframe>`?

Comment: No, I'm not using an iframe

Comment: Are there `<iframe>` elements at *outube page? Do `window.outerWidth` and `window.innerWidth` return same value?

Comment: The first node is also the lowest one. Try using appendChild and z-index like 999999999

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom

Comment: @guest271314 They return the same value. The webpage does have iframes but I don't think that the side and top bars are iframes.

Comment: The `html` at Question appears to be within an `iframe`?

Comment: @DanielHerr I think you're on to something there. Shadow DOM is completely new to me, would you mind giving me a little more direction as to how this will help the problem?

Answer (score 0):

consider adding `top: 0; left: 0; margin: 0;` to the styles.

There may be some quirkness involved with z-index and similar, but this may fix it. There may be a style that is purposely changing the `top,left,margin` style properties for everything inside a certain element or something similar

If this doesn't work, change the `position` to `fixed`. Chances are that the top bar and the left bar have fixed positions. Afaik, a fixed-positioned element will always be rendered on top of an absolute one, no matter the z-index

Comment: I set the top, left, and margin values to 0 for both the canvas and the canvasDiv but still no luck. No luck making the z-index bigger either. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Position didn't fix it but I found that your top/left/margin advice actually worked for a couple other pages where the canvas wasn't previously filling the entire area. Still not working for youtube, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a feature designed to isolate HTML and CSS components: Shadow DOM

```js
let shadow, shadowversion
try {
 shadow = document.body.attachShadow({ mode: "open" })
 shadowversion = 1
} catch(error) {
 shadow = document.body.createShadowRoot()
 shadowversion = 0
}
let canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight
shadow.appendChild(canvas)
let drawing = canvas.getContext("2d")
drawing.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
canvas.addEventListener("click", function() {
 if(shadowversion) {
  shadow.innerHTML = "<slot></slot>"
 } else {
  shadow.innerHTML = "<content></content>"
} })
```

```html
<body>Example Original Page</body>
```

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom

Comment: This isn't working for me so far. If I can get it working I'll come back and one-up your answer. It's saying that document.body.attachShadow isn't a function, but I'm guessing I need to go through all the documentation thoroughly to really understand what I'm doing. Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you on a version of Chrome older than 53?

Comment: Oh, I hadn't considered that. Mine is 49.0.2623.112. I don't think I can update because my mac is 10.7.5. Shoot.

Comment: Actually there is an older version. Just replace attachShadow({ mode }) with createShadowRoot() and <slot> with <content>, then use feature detection for different Chrome versions. Old api: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/

Comment: If I use an old version so that it's compatible with my version of chrome, will it also work for newer versions of chrome if I put the extension up in the web store? I actually messed around with the z-index more and for the time being it's covering the entirety of youtube. I have it set to 9999999999 for the canvas. I must've had one less nine before or something.

Comment: The old api is still supported but will probably be removed some time in the future, so you should try using both, something like `try { attachShadow } catch { createShadowRoot }`
Also, if you don't want to use Shadow DOM, a modal <dialog> may be the second best option, as the most recently shown modal <dialog> is guaranteed to be above any z-index element.